# Weird symbol in wchar_t char array

Tags: c++, wchar-t

[image: Here's a char array with a weird symbol that stops me from being able to compare it to a normal wchar_t array.]

What is causing this weird symbol occurring at the beginning of the array?

It occurs with Unicode character and Multibyte character sets. It's stopping me from being able to compare it to another array.

Edit: Google gave me nothing when researching "comparing Unicode strings c++".

I've also looked at historical weird symbols that have occured with wchar_ts, and they are sparse as well.

Edit: Visual studio 2010, Windows 7, code can't be shown. It's part of a structured storage file stream name.

I've given all the information I can. I'm opening and enumerating a structured storage file, and that wchar_t array is the pwcsName value once that stream has been enumerated. I'm looking for a way to compare it to "SummaryInformation". That symbol is in the way.

A possible solution I have thought of is creating a substring starting at the second char in the array, but I'm unsure as to how to go about doing that.

Comment: Some small hint about operating system, compiler, or even posting some code might *just* help a little.

Comment: That symbol indicates an character which has not symbol in your current font.  You'll need to find the character code (number) for it.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this any more than if you showed us a char* variable and asked where the first character was coming from. Where are you getting this string from?

Comment: "code can't be shown" == "question can't be answered"

Comment: @TWshal : My comments are *trying* to get you to give us enough information to make the question solveable and/or useful to others. Stackoverflow is all about 'showing your code'. If you really can't do that at all, it makes it very difficult for anyone to help you. In this case, (assuming there's *any* validity in my answer posted below) simply mentioning the specific name of the Windows function you were calling that returned the odd-looking name would have helped.

Comment: a png, a sarcastic snippet of code, and blaming a storage stream file name was NOT helpful in any way, and did not encourage me to divulge more information on something that's already pretty sensitive.

Comment: @RTwshal : Agreed, the png wasn't truly helpful, although it's part of the answer to the question "whats that weird square character?" (see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html for more on it). As for 'showing the code' : just a line or two is all that's needed, and by doing that you show that you've narrowed the problem down yourself. As for 'blaming' the file stream name: Isn't that actually the 'right' answer? Also if you show the code you're currently using to compare the two strings, I can show you how to change it to skip the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here about Windows Structured Storage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa380020(v=vs.85).aspx

In particular, the name parameter:-

> A pointer to a wide character null-terminated Unicode string that
>   contains the name of the newly created stream. The name can be used
>   later to open or reopen the stream. The name must not exceed 31
>   characters in length, not including the string terminator. **The 000
>   through 01f characters, serving as the first character of the
>   stream/storage name, are reserved for use by OLE.** This is a compound
>   file restriction, not a structured storage restriction.

So it's a reserved OLE name in some form. I don't know enough about structured storage to help you more, though.

Comment: Based on this answer I was able to find this snippet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379016(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That symbol is used to display a code point that does not have a glyph in the selected font. For example, the code point could be non-printable, or it could be a character from a language that is not included in the font your debugger is using.

It's impossible to say what the code point actually is from here. You will need to write some diagnostics code, or inspect in the debugger to find out what it really is.

In order to resolve the problem you'll need to track down where these strings are coming from. And then look to find out what you are doing wrong. It does look rather like an off-by-one error in your code. In other word, perhaps the string actually starts one character later than your code thinks it does.

Comment: The actual value has a hex value of 0x0005, what can I do to investigate this value?

Comment: Well, where did you get that value from?

Comment: Structured storage file stream name.

Comment: Well, it's a fault in the Structured storage file stream name then. Or else your code is stomping on it. Who can say?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I'm wondering too. All I'm trying to do is to help the asker diagnose the problem.

Comment: @couling That was not what happened here.